# how to test if an object is an instance of class in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

this is my simple person class and i want to check if an object is an instance of class

```
export class Person {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
}
```

```
import {Person} from './person';

let person = {
firstName: 'dev',
lastName: 'john',
} as Person;

test('test if person is an instance of Person', () => {
  expect(person).toBeInstanceOf(Person);
});
```

then i got this message

```
Message:
expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)

    Expected constructor: Person
    Received constructor: Object
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not code related.

Just in case somebody goes through the same, add `--no-cache` options to jest command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried adding `--no-cache` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`Person` *is* an `Object` they way you are creating it

use;

```js
let person = new Person()
person.firstName = 'dev'
person.lastName = 'john'
```

or add an appropriate `constructor` to your class and call it

```js
let person = new Person({
  firstName: 'dev',
  lastName: 'john',
})
```